# read and concatenate xml attributes using shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I have an xml:

```
<element attr1="val11" attr2="val12" attr3="val13" />
<element attr1="val21" attr2="val22" attr3="val23" />
<element attr1="val31" attr2="val32" attr3="val33" />
```

I need to get an output like below, using shell script:

```
val11(val13)
val21(val23)
val31(val33)
```

Comment: This XML seems invalid.

Answer (score 1):

awk -F 'attr1="|attr3="|" ' '{print $2"("$(NF-1)")" }' file

Answer (score 1):

The right way to extract contents from XML is with a real, live XML parser. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) is onesuch.

Note that this requires your data to be *actual XML*, which your existing data isn't without a root element being added.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//element' -v ./@attr1 -o '(' -v ./@attr3 -o ')' -n <<EOF
<root>
<element attr1="val11" attr2="val12" attr3="val13" />
<element attr1="val21" attr2="val22" attr3="val23" />
<element attr1="val31" attr2="val32" attr3="val33" />
</root>
EOF
```

---

To explain how this works:

- `-t` starts a new template
- `-m //element` matches an element named `element` anywhere in your document.
- `-v ./@attr1` emits the content of the attribute named `attr1`
- `-o '('` emits a literal `(` as a string
- `-v ./@attr3` emits the content of the attribute named `attr3`
- `-o ')'` emits a literal `)` as a string
- `-n` emits a literal newline

---

If you want to be able to run this on machines that don't have XMLStarlet installed, you can generate an XSLT template, and invoke that with XSLTProc, which is widely available.

Running `xmlstarlet sel -C -t -m '//element' -v ./@attr1 -o '(' -v ./@attr3 -o ')' -n` emits the following XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//element">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@attr1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@attr3"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you save this as `myproc.xslt`, and run  `xsltproc myproc.xslt - <input.xml`, you'll get the desired output on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split($2,a,"=");split($4,b,"=");gsub(/"/,"",a[2]);gsub(/"/,"",b[2]);print a[2]"("b[2] ")"}' xml
val11(val13)
val21(val23)
val31(val33)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use sed as below;

```
sed 's/^.*1="//g;s/" .*.="/(/;s/" \/>/)/g' yourXMl
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ sed 's/^.*1="//g;s/" .*.="/(/;s/" \/>/)/g' t1
val11(val13)
val21(val23)
val31(val33)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR.. we can do this with perl..

Tested on CentOS7

cat your file to this filter as shown below...

```
Tue Oct 04|22:41:36|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp> cat c.txt
<element attr1="val11" attr2="val12" attr3="val13" />
<element attr1="val21" attr2="val22" attr3="val23" />
<element attr1="val31" attr2="val32" attr3="val33" />
Tue Oct 04|22:41:38|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp> cat c.txt |perl -pe 's/^.+r1=\"(.+?)\".+r3=\"(.+?)\" .*$/\1(\2)/g'
val11(val13)
val21(val23)
val31(val33)
Tue Oct 04|22:41:40|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp>
```

Answer (score 0):

awk -F'[="]' '{print $3 "("$(NF-1)")"}' file

```
val11(val13)
val21(val23)
val31(val33)
```